# How to insert Spark DataFrame to Hive Internal table without duplicating?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

So command to append spark dataframe directly to hive table is,

```
df.write().mode("append").saveAsTable("tableName")
```

But does the append mode make sure it will avoid duplicating of rows?
eg:

- if row A is in hive table and its also in spark dataframe
- appending spark dataframe to hive table will result in two rows of A?

Is there a way to make sure duplication doesn't happen while appending?

**Edit:**
There are two ways to go:

- one mentioned by [shu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7632695/shu), load hive table as spark dataframe, merge two dataframes, drop duplicates and write back to hive table with mode as 'overwrite'.
- second, load hive table to temp table, append dataframe to temp table, get distinct rows and overwrite temp table back to hive table.

What I am looking for is, is there a way to do all of it directly without having an intermediate step of writing data to some temp table or dataframe?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Appending spark dataframe to hive table will result ***two rows of A***.

To make sure duplication doesn't happen while Appending then

1. You need to load the entire hive table into another data frame(df1)
   **before appending the data into the table**.
2. Then **union two data frames**(df,df1) and apply `.dropDuplicates()` (or)
   `window functions` to get  your required record from the duplicated
   records.

   **Example:**

   `union_df=df.union(df1)`

   `union_df.dropDuplicates()` (or) `use window function`
3. Then write the data into new 
   table(`union_df.write().mode("append").saveAsTable("newtableName")`)
   then finally select the data from the **new table overwrite the
   existing hive table.**

   **Example:**

   `spark.sql("insert overwrite table <database>.<existing_table> select * from <database>.<new_table>"))`
4. Finally drop the new table that 
   `spark.sql("drop table <database>.<new_table>")`

By using this way you are going to have data not duplicated in the hive table.

Answer (score -1):

None of what you ask is possible with df.write. Sorry. I.e. you will get 2 rows potentially.